# Generating code with Hibernate 4 - Exception with "detect many-to-many tables"

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

First of all I'd like to thank everyone that's even reading this.

I'm trying to generate code for my application but I'm getting this error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table
module_application_status refers to an unmapped class: persistenceGen.ModuleApplication
An association from the table module_application_status refers to an unmapped class: persistenceGen.ModuleApplication
```

This is the part of my database diagram that generates the error:

[image: Diagram]
<sub>(source: [akamaihd.net](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/74777_707832512567265_1426711129_n.jpg))</sub>

What seems to be happening is that the code generation treats the module_application table as a pure link table between module and application tables, not generating the ModuleAppication class.

There is probably a way of forcing the generation of this class without loosing the Set in the Module class, but as I'm still learning how to use the Hibernate framework, I don't know how. Can anyone help me with that?
Any additional information requested will be promptly posted here.

Edit:
I guess I forgot to tell that I'm trying to use reverse engineering to generate the files.

Here is my cfg.xml file. Just deleted the pwd line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/domotics</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">domotics</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
        <mapping class="persistenceGen.Activeusersessions" />
        <mapping class="persistenceGen.Location" />
        <mapping class="persistenceGen.User" />
        <mapping class="persistenceGen.Communication" />
        <mapping class="persistenceGen.SceneModuleApplicationStatus" />
        <mapping class="persistenceGen.Module" />
        <mapping class="persistenceGen.ModuleApplicationStatus" />
        <mapping class="persistenceGen.WaitingApplication" />
        <mapping class="persistenceGen.ModuleApplication" />
        <mapping class="persistenceGen.Scene" />
        <mapping class="persistenceGen.Parameter" />
        <mapping class="persistenceGen.Waiting" />
        <mapping class="persistenceGen.Command" />
        <mapping class="persistenceGen.Application" />
        <mapping class="persistenceGen.Status" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Edit:

Now I can generate the files via Reverse Engineering using a custom Reverse Engineering Strategy in which I override the "isManyToManyTable" method. I compare the table name and, if it's module_application I return false. I'm not getting the association error anymore, but now I don't have a set of applications in my module class, does anybody know how to deal with that?

Comment: Can you post your class mappings?

Comment: @Thihara, you mean the cfg.xml?

Comment: No the class level hibernate mappings. If you are annotating post the classes them selves. Just the necessary ones.

Comment: @Thihara, I'm using Annotations, but since I'm getting this error, I can't generate the classes to post here!

Comment: @Thihara, I forgot to make it clear that I'm using reverse engineering.